# What can we deduce from the contrapositive of this continuity claim?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $x:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$, $b>a\ge0$, $I\subseteq(a,b]$ and $r>0$.

Consider the following claim: There is a $\delta>0$ such that $$\forall s,t\in(a,b]:0<t-s<\delta\text{ and }(s,t]\cap I=\emptyset\Rightarrow|x(s)-x(t)|<r\tag1.$$

Assuming that the claim doesn't hold, we can conclude that there are $(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb N},(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[a,b]$ with \begin{align}0<t_k-s_k&<\frac1k;\tag2\\ (s_k,t_k]\cap I&=\emptyset;\tag3\\|x(s)-x(t)|&\ge r\tag4\end{align} for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, passing to a subsequence if necessary, we can assume that $$s_k,t_k\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}t\tag5$$ for some $t\in[a,b]$.

> However, this is not sufficient for me. I would like to achieve that, assuming there is no $\delta>0$ with $(1)$, that we can choose $(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ and $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ in such a way that they (or a subsequence) converge to $t$ from the left and right, respectively. Is this possible?

My idea is that we should be able to achieve that $(s_{k+1},t_{k+1}]\subseteq(s_k,t_k]$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ without violating $(2)$-$(4)$ ... Is this possible (and sufficient)?

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude (5) without some further argument. Compactness tells you that the $s_k$ and $t_k$ have convergent subsequences, but why should they have convergent subsequences with a common limit and why should (2) hold when you replace $s_k$ and $t_k$ by their convergent subsequences.

Comment: @RobArthan Compactness of $[a,b]$ implies that $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ has a subsequence $(t_{k_l})_{l\in\mathbb N}$ s.t. $t_{k_l}\xrightarrow{l\to\infty}t$ for some $t\in[a,b]$. Now $s_{k_l}=t_{k_l}-(t_{k_l}-s_{k_l})\xrightarrow{l\to\infty}t$ by $(2)$.